# eval creating problems in evaluating

Tags: javascript, exception, eval

i am using eval to convert string decimals to decimals.

```
eval("000451.01");
```

When i am using the above statement javascript it throws exception 'expected ;'

and when using `eval("000451");` it gives me a different result.

anyone has got any idea??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should **not** use `eval` to parse numbers; it will be orders of magnitude slower than normal methods.

Instead, you should use the `parseFloat` function. like this:  `parseFloat("000451.01")`.

The reason you're getting the error is that Javascript treats numbers that begin with `0` as octal numbers, which cannot have decimals.

If you want to parse an integer, call `parseInt`, and make sure to give a second parameter of `10` to force it to parse base 10 numbers, or you'll get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers starting with a zero are interpreted as octal numbers. But octal numbers are only integers and not floating point numbers. So try this:

```
eval("451.01")
```

But it would be better if you use the [`parseFloat` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseFloat):

```
parseFloat("000451.01")
```

Comment: `parseFloat` doesn't take a base parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, a token starting with zero is an integer literal in base 8. `000451` in base 8 is `297` in base 10, and `000451.01` is parsed as `int(297) dot int(1)` instead of a single number literal.

Remove the initial zeros and it should work.